# Detect user download on intenet explorer add-on dll

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, add-on

I am developing an add-on to internet explorer (that's a dll attached to iexplorer process).

I am trying to achieve the following: when a user tries to download a **file**, block it, send the link to some antivirus server for inspection.

For now, I have the following code (I wrote it in simple console app for now):

```
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
IE.BeforeNavigate2 += IE_BeforeNavigate2;
IE.Visible = true;
Console.ReadKey();
//...
static void IE_BeforeNavigate2(object pDisp, ref object URL, ref object Flags, ref object TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, ref object Headers, ref bool Cancel)
{
   //validate that the url is a file link...
    Cancel=true;
    // send URL.ToString(); for inspection
}
```

[InternetExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v%3Dvs.85))

The problem: this event called for every navigation I made, but I want to detect a user download.

i.e when user clicks:

[image]

I also tried using

```
IE.DownloadBegin += IE_DownloadBegin;
IE.FileDownload += IE_FileDownload;
```

But those events doesn't fires when user clicks the download button.

Comment: IE_FileDownload event occurs before downloading gets started. you can set VARIANT_TRUE parameter which cancels the download process. Then you can develop your logic for checking the file. The Save button you are referring to is from a PDF viewer. There is no event for it.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT For now I will use `IE_FileDownload` combined with `BeforeNavigate2` events

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding